# Android components are not matched in position when running the app using phone

Tags: android, android-layout

I placed a button in the middle of design layout from activity_main.xml but when i run the app through my phone, the positioning is not the same as the design inside activity_main.xml.

Tried to change layout to relative and the problem still exist.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="276dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I expect that the design position from activity_main is the same when run through an actual android phone.

From the design layout

[image: a busy cat]

from the actual phone

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Have you connected the sides of the button to the corresponding sides of the screen, thus creating a constraint?

Comment: show your xml code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might want to adjust button relatively with other components. i.e. try to align your button on top of other component or maybe on bottom of another component.

Refer this link, it has all information

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_alignBottom

If you have confusion, share whole xml file for us to refer.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to change the `<ConstraintLayout/>` in `<RelativeLayout/>` and replace the `Button` code by this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove that margins from attributes. There is the left margin which make your button to go right and top margin which move button below the actual center point in small density devices.

So If you want to add button in center of screen in all devices. Use below code without any margin. But if your want to add spacing between other view then use small margin in other views.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Refer this guide to learn basics of constraints : [guide](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efeff1">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```